# bring -f option to multi module

Tags: maven, maven-2

there is `-f` option in maven, that allows to specify alternate `pom.xml` file. Is there a possibility, that I can also bring this behaviour to the executed modules? Now it looks like, that when I have this structure:

```
projectA: pom.xml pom.xml2
projectB: pom.xml pom.xml2
```

And when I run maven with `-f pom.xml2` option as reactor with projectB specified as module, it looks like that it picks `pom.xml2` from the projectA, and it picks `pom.xml` from projectB. Is there a way, how can I propagate the `-f` option to the modules?
Thanks for answering.

Comment: Are your poms to different to implement them as profiles in one pom? Active profiles would get propagated to all builds in a reactor.

Answer (score 2):

Because we can specified pom file in module definition.[1](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1493?focusedCommentId=308389#comment-308389)
Here's an example for using alternative pom file in module.

```
<modules>
    <module>child1/pom-jdk14.xml</module>
    <module>child2/pom-jdk14.xml</module>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jörn Horstmann comments I would try lots of things to get this working with profiles in one pom.

If that's not possible the only way I can think of to get this working is to bypass the normal maven mechanism by using a "switching pom" with profiles. This pom is put as pom.xml in each module and has a profile for each of your pom.xml2 (or others) and in that profile executes another maven build f.e. via the antrun-plugin with the -f for the pom you need:

```
<profile>
            <id>xml2</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build pom.xml2</id>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase> <!-- whatever suits you -->
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                                <echo level="info" message="Building pom.xml2..." />
                                                <exec executable="cmd" dir=".">
                                                    <arg value="/c" />
                                                    <arg value="mvn" />
                                                    <arg value="-f" />
                                                    <arg value="pom.xml2" />
                                                    <arg value="install" /> <!-- enter which phase you need -->
                                                </exec>
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```